# How to clear textbox value?

Tags: wix

In my CustomUI I am trying to validate the logon service account by entering the username and password. The Test button will validate the credentials. If it is an invalid account, it will show a spawndialog with an error,  and on clicking will return to the same CustomUI. While returning back the username and password textbox value should be empty. What is the best way to clear out the textbox values? I tried by setting the property of the textbox value to empty, but the installer get failed.

Answer (score 2):

On the close button control of your modal dialog you can put a set property control event that sets those properties back to empty.  ( {} means empty in MSI )  Be sure to get the controlevent order correct so that the properties get set before the dialog is closed.

But, I'm not sure this will work.  I'm not positive that the original dialog will refresh that data correctly.  There are certain limitations of MSI UI and this might be one of those cases.  (I'd have to mock it up to confirm. )

If you do his this limitation, the workaround is to do a NewDialog instead of a SpawnDialog and on that dialog tell the user there is a problem and only offer them a back button to the previous dialog.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with first option it doesn't work for me. I want to use only the spawndialog don't need to show separate dialog for the error. did you get info on this?

Comment: It is what it is.  The internal UI for MSI is from the 1990's and you have to live with it's limitations or roll your own external UI handler.